# PHP foreach loop from a text file

Tags: php, foreach

I'm having trouble with a foreach loop from a text file. I have a directory tree, and a list of these directories is in a text file, I want to check the tree against the list, and echo if any directories are missing.

The problem that I'm having is that I can't see an account for a new line, so if the file has 1 line, then it returns that it exists, but if the file has two line it returns the first as missing and the second as existing, even if it's the same entry twice in the file - see code below for clarification

```
<?php
  $logFile = 'LogFile.txt';
  $rootDirectory = 'C:\testdir\\';
  $verificationFile = 'verificationfiles/directoryverification.txt';
  $verificationContents = file($verificationFile);
  $fh = fopen($logFile,'a') or die("can't open file");
  $new_line = "\r\n";
  
 foreach($verificationContents as $directoryName) {
    $subDirectory = $rootDirectory.$directoryName;
    echo "$subDirectory <br />";
     
    
    if (file_exists($subDirectory)) {
     echo "$subDirectory Exists <br />";
    } else {
    echo "$subDirectory Does Not Exist <br />";
     $libverificationfailed = 'failed';
    fwrite($fh, "$subDirectory Not Found");
    fwrite($fh, $new_line);
    }
    
    
 }
?>
```

So, as an example, the root directory has 2 sub directories, subdir1 and subdir2.

## directoryverification.txt

```
subdir1  
subdir2
```

**and the page echos**

> C:\testdir\subdir1
> C:\testdir\subdir1 Does Not Exist
> C:\testdir\subdir2
> C:\testdir\subdir2 Exists

So if there is a new line after the data in the text file, the code isn't reading it correctly. I'm hoping that this makes sense and that somebody can help.

regards,

Comment: From [the documentation](http://php.net/file): **Note:** Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** is used, so you still need to use [rtrim()](http://php.net/rtrim) if you do not want the line ending present.

Comment: Thanks rickdenhaan,

    $subDirectory = rtrim($subDirectory);

Just before the if statement sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks rickdenhaan,

```
$subDirectory = rtrim($subDirectory);
```

Just before the if statement sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $rootDirectory = 'C:\testdir\\';
    $verificationFile = 'verificationfiles/directoryverification.txt';
    $file = new \SplFileObject($verificationFile, 'r');
    $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);

    while ( $dirname = $file->fgets() )
    {
        $dirname = $rootDirectory . trim($dirname);

        if ( !file_exists($dirname) )
        {
            echo sprintf("direcrory %s does not exist\n", $dirname); 
            continue;
        }

        echo sprintf("direcrory %s exists\n", $dirname); 
    }
```

Comment: How would i set the directory that i'm checking as a variable though?

In mine, the directory i'm searching is set to C testdir but this would need to be changed from time to time